# Como percorrer os valores de um HashMap através de uma determinada chave?

Tags: java, hashmap

Como eu posso percorrer os valores de um HashMap através de uma determinada chave?

Um exemplo para ilustrar: tenho um HashMap chamado valores, com uma chave que é uma id representada por String e um valor que é um inteiro.

```
HashMap<String, Integer> valores = new HashMap<String,Integer>();

valores.put("Id01",13);
valores.put("Id02",4);
valores.put("Id01",37);
valores.put("Id01",49);
valores.put("Id02",9);
valores.put("Id01",78);
valores.put("Id03",5);
valores.put("Id01",90);
```

Como eu faço para, por exemplo, fazer um loop/for pra percorrer o HashMap e imprimir todos os valores do HashMap pertencente a chave "Id01"? Gerando o seguinte resultado no console:
13
37
49
78
90

Comment: Como, sendo que não é possível ter múltiplas chaves iguais em um `HashMap`?

Comment: Então, eu não sabia. Obrigado.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você está usando o `HashMap` de maneira incorreta. Para cada chave há apenas um valor (embora o contrário não seja verdade). Então quando você faz isso:

```
valores.put("Id01",13);
valores.put("Id01",37);
```

O único que vai valer é o último, porque para a chave `Id01` só poderá haver um único valor.

O que você quer de verdade é que possa haver múltiplos valores para uma chave. E então o que acho que você quer é uma destas quatro coisas:

1. `Map<String, List<Integer>>` - Se cada valor chave pode ter múltiplos valores inteiros associados, e a ordem deles deve ser a mesma em que foram inseridos e eles podem se repetir.
2. `Map<String, Set<Integer>>` ou `Map<String, SortedSet<Integer>>`, aonde o `SortedSet<Integer>` ou `Set<Integer>` é um `TreeSet` - Se cada valor pode ter múltiplos valores inteiros associados, e a ordem deles deve ser uma ordem crescente e eles não podem se repetir.
3. `Map<String, Set<Integer>>`, aonde o `Set<Integer>` é um `LinkedHashSet` - Se cada valor pode ter múltiplos valores inteiros associados, e a ordem deles deve ser a mesma em que foram inseridos e eles não podem se repetir.
4. `Map<String, Set<Integer>>`, aonde o `Set<Integer>` é um `HashSet` - Se cada valor pode ter múltiplos valores inteiros associados, e a ordem deles não interessa e pode ser qualquer uma e eles não podem se repetir.

Outra consideração a fazer é se esse seu `Map` poderá ou não sofrer alterações após ter todos os seus dados iniciais populados:

- Colocando isso em código, talvez você queira isso:

  ```
  public void xx1() {
      Map<String, List<Integer>> valores = new HashMap<>(10);
      valores.put("Id01", Arrays.asList(13, 37, 49, 78, 50));
      valores.put("Id02", Arrays.asList(4, 9));
      valores.put("Id03", Arrays.asList(5));
  }
  ```

  Neste código acima, a ordem dos valores é a mesma em que foram inseridos e alterações futuras não são muito bem vindas.
- Ou isso:

  ```
  public void xx2() {
      Map<String, List<Integer>> valores = new HashMap<>(10);
      valores.put("Id01", new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(13, 37, 49, 78, 50)));
      valores.put("Id02", new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(4, 9)));
      valores.put("Id03", new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(5)));
  }
  ```

  Já neste código, alterações futuras são muito bem-vindas, diferente do primeiro caso.
- Ou talvez isso:

  ```
  public void xx3() {
      Map<String, Set<Integer>> valores = new HashMap<>(10);
      valores.put("Id01", new LinkedHashSet<>(Arrays.asList(13, 37, 49, 78, 50)));
      valores.put("Id02", new LinkedHashSet<>(Arrays.asList(4, 9)));
      valores.put("Id03", new LinkedHashSet<>(Arrays.asList(5)));
  }
  ```

  Aqui alterações futuras são bem vindas, mas repetições não são permitidas. A ordem dos números é a ordem em que foram inseridos.
- Ou então isso:

  ```
  public void xx4() {
      Map<String, Set<Integer>> valores = new HashMap<>(10);
      valores.put("Id01", new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(13, 37, 49, 78, 50)));
      valores.put("Id02", new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(4, 9)));
      valores.put("Id03", new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(5)));
  }
  ```

  Aqui alterações futuras são bem vindas, repetições não são permitidas, mas a ordem dos números não interessa.
- Ou isso:

  ```
  public void xx5() {
      Map<String, Set<Integer>> valores = new HashMap<>(10);
      valores.put("Id01", new HashSet<>(10));
      valores.put("Id02", new HashSet<>(10));
      valores.put("Id03", new HashSet<>(10));

      valores.get("Id01").add(13);
      valores.get("Id02").add(4);
      valores.get("Id01").add(37);
      valores.get("Id01").add(49);
      valores.get("Id02").add(9);
      valores.get("Id01").add(78);
      valores.get("Id03").add(5);
      valores.get("Id01").add(90);
  }
  ```

  Aqui os valores são inseridos um-a-um após o `Map` ter sido criado e repetições não são permitidas. A ordem dos valores não interessa (se interessar, é só trocar o `new HashSet<>(10)` por `new LinkedHashSet<>(10)` ou `new TreeSet<>()`. Ideal para o caso aonde o `Map` vai sofrer alterações após ter sido criado.
- Ou quem sabe isso:

  ```
  public void xx6() {
      Map<String, List<Integer>> valores = new HashMap<>(10);
      valores.put("Id01", new ArrayList<>(10));
      valores.put("Id02", new ArrayList<>(10));
      valores.put("Id03", new ArrayList<>(10));

      valores.get("Id01").add(13);
      valores.get("Id02").add(4);
      valores.get("Id01").add(37);
      valores.get("Id01").add(49);
      valores.get("Id02").add(9);
      valores.get("Id01").add(78);
      valores.get("Id03").add(5);
      valores.get("Id01").add(90);
  }
  ```

  Semelhante ao anterior, mas repetições são permitidas e a ordem dos números é a ordem em que foram inseridos.
- Ou talvez até isso, usando Java 8:

  ```
  public BiFunction<String, List<Integer>, List<Integer>> add(int i) {
      return (k, v) -> {
          List<Integer> list = v != null ? v : new ArrayList<>(10);
          list.add(i);
          return list;
      };
  }

  public void xx7() {
      Map<String, List<Integer>> valores = new HashMap<>(10);
      valores.compute("Id01", add(13));
      valores.compute("Id02", add(4));
      valores.compute("Id01", add(37));
      valores.compute("Id01", add(49));
      valores.compute("Id02", add(9));
      valores.compute("Id01", add(78));
      valores.compute("Id03", add(5));
      valores.compute("Id01", add(90));
  }
  ```

Comment: Você me ajudou muito. Muito obrigado! Não estava claro realmente o conceito de HashMap pra mim e as alternativas ampliaram as possibilidades.

Answer (score 1):

Amigo,

Seu conceito de HashMap está errado. Você precisará modificar o tipo de dados (assinatura) do seu HashMap.

```
HashMap<String, Integer[]> valores = new HashMap<String,Integer[]>();
```

Após isso, pode-se atribuir chaves e valores dessa forma:

```
valores.put("Id01",new Integer[]{13,37,49,78,90});
valores.put("Id02",new Integer[]{4,9});
valores.put("Id03",new Integer[]{5});
```

Agora é só fazer o laço e a consistência:

```
// vamos obter uma view dos mapeamentos
Set set = valores.entrySet();

// obtemos um iterador
Iterator i = set.iterator();

// e finalmente exibimos todas as chaves e seus valores
while(i.hasNext()) {
    Map.Entry<String, Integer[]> entrada = (Map.Entry<String, Integer[]>)i.next();
    if (entrada.getKey().equals("Id01")) {
        for (Integer valor : entrada.getValue()) {
            System.out.println("Valor é: "+valor);
        }
    }
}
```