# Utilizando um map para armazenar 1 ID para N valores?

Tags: android, hashmap, iterator

**EDIT** por ausência de detalhes, repostei a questão [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/59652/como-percorrer-os-valores-de-um-hashmap-atrav%C3%A9s-de-uma-determinada-chave). A pergunta foi sinalizada e um moderador irá deletá-la assim que possível, obrigado.

Eu tenho os seguintes IDs e valores, respectivamente:

```
1 - 18;
1 - 19;
1 - 20;
3 - 21;
3 - 22;
8 - 23;
8 -24;
8 - 25;
11 - 26;
3 - 27;
3 - 28;
```

Como eu posso fazer para que, quando eu passe o valor do ID via parâmetro, ele me retorne os valores deste ID? POr exemplo, se eu passasse o ID 3, ele me retornaria os valores 21, 22, 27 & 28.

Eu deveria usar um `map <integer, List<Integer>>`, correto? Mas como eu posso fazer isso? Como também eu faria para adicionar estes valores dentro do meu List?

Comment: Diego, como e onde você está escrevendo esses valores?

Comment: Estes valores provém do banco de dados local SQLite. O ID (primeiro valor) se refere à um produto, e o valor (segundo valor) de um cálculo. Então, por exemplo, o ID 3 é uma guitarra que possui 4 cálculos diferentes, com os IDs 21, 22, 27 & 28

Comment: então, quando o usuário clicar no produto do ID 3, eu tenho que verificar quais são os cálculos que estão conectados com ele. aí que está o problema. Eu acho que o map desse jeito é a forma mais fácil, mas posso estar errado!

Comment: Em vez de carregar os dados todos e colocá-los em um `map` você deve ir buscá-los ao banco apenas quando o usuário escolher o ID, trazendo as linhas que tenham esse ID.

Answer (score 1):

Voce pode utilizar [HashMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html).
 Faz o seguinte:

```
  HashMap<Integer,ArrayList<Integer>> map=new HashMap<Integer,ArrayList<Integer>>();  
      //  chave = 3  ,  {1,22,27,28}
   map.put(3, new ArrayList<Integer>(Arrays.asList(1,22,27,28)));
   System.out.println( "Valores : " + map.get(3));
   // Resultado = "Valores : [1, 22, 27, 28]"
```

Onde 3 é a chave, basta trocar a chave e iniciar um novo ArrayList de Integer

Comment: Muito obrigado pela resposta, bom amigo! Mas infelizmente a minha questão é um pouco mais complexa, eu precisaria fazer isso com todos os valores da lista. Como que eu aplicaria um for nessa lógica?

Comment: Por exemplo, enquanto o ID fosse o 3, ele ia adicionando no arraylist da key 3. Aí quando ele fosse pro ID 11, adicionava os valores no array do ID 11, mas e se ele voltasse pro 3, e etc?

Comment: Que estrutura está armazenado essa lista? Porque não ordena ela por ID?

Comment: Outra coisa que voce pode fazer também, é ler todo o arquivo e gerar o array list, e só depois colocar no HashMap

Comment: Então cara, aí que tá. Eu tô conseguindo exibir cada valor num print, tipo, do jeito que mandei ali em cima, eu só tô me quebrando para armazenar. Vou estudar a lógica do cavalheiro ali embaixo e ver se eu consigo algo

Comment: Amigo, obrigado pela resposta mas minha pergunta foi muito mal formulada e eu ainda não consigo encontrar uma solução. Vou deletá-la e reformular.

Answer (score 0):

Segue a lógica para gerenciar o map, para buscar o valor basta usar o get passando o id. Qualquer dúvida sobre o código é só perguntar.

```
Map<integer, List<Integer>> map  = new HashMap<integer, List<Integer>>();

public void adicionar(Integer id, Integer elemento){
  if(map.containsKey(id)){
     map.get(id).add(elemento);
  }else{
     List<Integer>> lista = new ArrayList();
     lista.add(elemento);
     map.put(id,lista);
  }
}
```

Comment: Amigo, obrigado pela resposta mas minha pergunta foi muito mal formulada e eu ainda não consigo encontrar uma solução. Vou deletá-la e reformular.